# JavaScript grouping array with age group and find largest date

Tags: javascript, arrays, grouping

I am trying to implement something like for each age group, I wanted to find the largest date, and then compare with today's date, get the date differences and store into another separate array. Here is some sample input:

```
//removed
```

I sorted the array into ascending order:

```
frequentarr.sort(function(a, b) {
    da = new Date(a.date);
    db = new Date(b.date);
    if (da == db) {
        return 0;
    }
    return da > db ? 1 : -1;
});
console.log(frequentarr);
```

My age group array:

```
var ageGroup = ['>=80', '70-79', '60-69', '50-59', '40-49', '30-39', '20-29', '10-19', '0-9'];
```

I not sure how to actually group the account according to age group, and then for each age group, find the largest date. After that, compare with today's date to find the date differences.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Since you have them sorted by age, you could implement this using a _control break_. You could also divide the data up into sub-arrays by age group upfront, if that makes things easier for you.

Comment: FYI, your date format is “sortable” using string comparison, so you don’t necessarily have to create Date objects in your sort callback function. Might speed things up, especially if you’re dealing with larger amounts of data.

Comment: `da == db` will **always** be false. They're different objects (even if they contain the same dat). If you want to sort by date, simply `return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date);` (because `-` will coerce those dates to numbers). But it's unclear how your code is meant to do anything with *groups* of dates.

Comment: @NinaScholz Edited question!

Comment: Also note, re @CBroe's comment about sorting the strings, that those strings aren't in a format `new Date()` is required to parse. It may parse it, or not, depending on the implementation. So sorting by string might be better (`return a.date.localeCompare(b.date);`).

Comment: Instead of `'70-79'`, I would rather specify the age groups as `[70, 79]` - so you can access lower and upper boundary directly, and do not have to start splitting string values at that point first. The `>=80` group could simply become `[80, 999]` or something like that; or you could also use `false` or `null` as the second value, to indicate that there is no upper boundary for that group. (Of course for the latter your logic would have to specifically check for that.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But the current one is actually sorting the date in ascending order as you can see from the sample input :)

Comment: @CBroe Hmm that one is meant for me to plot the label for the charts at the later part :)

Comment: @guest176969: Your code will definitely sort equal dates incorrectly. (It will sort unequal dates fine **if** the browser you're using happens to parse that unspecified format correctly.) Again, `==` with different date objects is always false.

Comment: But you will need the age group boundaries before that already - and in that format, they are simply easier to handle for comparison. And making `[70, 79]` into  `70-79` later on for displaying purposes is no big deal.

Comment: is the question about sorting or finding or grouping or ...? and which result do you expect?

Comment: @NinaScholz It is about grouping according to age group then find the largest date for each age group

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ah I see I see. Thanks so much for pointing it out! :)

Comment: @CBroe I am accessing the age index by these at the later part: var age = frequentarr[i].age;
  ageIndex = Math.floor(age / 10);
  ageIndex = 8 - ageIndex;  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the age and divide by `10` for the group and check if the date is greater than stored. If not, take the actual date.

```js
var array = [{ age: 67, date: "2017/01/09" }, { age: 11, date: "2017/01/14" }, { age: 11, date: "2017/01/14" }, { age: 62, date: "2017/01/15" }, { age: 40, date: "2017/01/21" }, { age: 21, date: "2017/02/08" }, { age: 12, date: "2017/02/18" }, { age: 56, date: "2017/02/29" }, { age: 24, date: "2017/03/03" }, { age: 22, date: "2017/03/17" }, { age: 66, date: "2017/03/25" }, { age: 62, date: "2017/04/03" }, { age: 59, date: "2017/05/18" }, { age: 39, date: "2017/06/14" }, { age: 19, date: "2017/07/03" }, { age: 31, date: "2017/07/10" }, { age: 24, date: "2017/07/14" }, { age: 36, date: "2017/07/24" }, { age: 36, date: "2017/07/24" }, { age: 73, date: "2017/08/17" }, { age: 63, date: "2017/10/01" }, { age: 16, date: "2017/10/14" }, { age: 70, date: "2017/10/18" }, { age: 29, date: "2017/12/03" }, { age: 15, date: "2017/12/07" }, { age: 47, date: "2017/12/19" }, { age: 11, date: "2017/12/25" }, { age: 26, date: "2017/12/28" }],
    groups = [];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    var group = Math.floor(o.age / 10);

    if (groups[group] >= o.date) {
        return;
    }
    groups[group] = o.date;
});

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first sort the `frequentarray` by the date, then simply group it using reduce. I'm using a Map, so you can simply get the latest date within a age group using

```
m.get(<ageGroup>)[0];
```

```js
let frequentarr = [{accountID: "-Ks8mWcr2x08gEbSCSuJ", age: 67, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/01/09"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWh4j7fv7XaQyygJ", age: 11, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/01/14"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWh4j7fv7XaQyygJ", age: 11, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/01/14"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWayOns5WnK0xu3e", age: 62, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/01/15"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWYnb4fu1AT9vR8X", age: 40, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/01/21"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWf0deAAVlOSb2qS", age: 21, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/02/08"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWbH4YQhXg9DZvjG", age: 12, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/02/18"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWZpiUOt8aXyEY22", age: 56, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/02/29"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mW_HvNJ3RKCz6QZk", age: 24, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/03/03"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWgBmSBh6LrsLMU4", age: 22, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/03/17"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWgceHTuJsBObl_C", age: 66, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/03/25"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWYhd7WuUGJMUTzx", age: 62, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/04/03"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWhQ-TsvAbvS0Sk2", age: 59, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/05/18"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWY4PQ3stDWTlriB", age: 39, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/06/14"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWYMZw8YTs6P-UCk", age: 19, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/07/03"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWcm1zYkSQN2fD9c", age: 31, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/07/10"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWalbiAq35e10lZy", age: 24, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/07/14"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWjmbuBtmzzJ2IPu", age: 36, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/07/24"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWjmbuBtmzzJ2IPu", age: 36, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/07/24"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWbNJ53rNuspHlQe", age: 73, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/08/17"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWcvM1-w0GAl-eHs", age: 63, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/10/01"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWhvTEp83PziAxpp", age: 16, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/10/14"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWdGfSrC-5n8ywNs", age: 70, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/10/18"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWdf0LfFKWH8-YBF", age: 29, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/12/03"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWhtA-3ExwVUWZC_", age: 15, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/12/07"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWX4R6inD83AO4rZ", age: 47, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/12/19"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWh4j7fv7XaQyygJ", age: 11, gender: "female", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/12/25"},
    {accountID: "-Ks8mWadHFzJ1VGmN60k", age: 26, gender: "male", brand: "Akira", date: "2017/12/28"}];

let ageGroups = ['80-1000', '70-79', '60-69', '50-59', '40-49', '30-39', '20-29', '10-19', '0-9'];

function getAgeRange(age) {
    return ageGroups.find(e => {
        let s = e.split('-');
        return age >= s[0] && age <= s[1];
    })
}

let m = frequentarr.sort((a,b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)).reduce((a,b) => {
    let r = getAgeRange(b.age);
    return a.set(r, a.has(r) ? a.get(r).concat(b) : [b])
}, new Map);

console.log(m);
```